# SQL query working and not working

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

I already asked some questions to make this query, but still not working as it should:
If I use this SQL code, it works:

```
SELECT
   l.inlog AS inlog,
   u.naam AS naam,
   SUM(o.status='afgewerkt') AS oefn
FROM 
   users AS u
LEFT JOIN     
   llntoets AS l ON (u.inlog = l.inlog)
LEFT JOIN     
   oefeningen AS o ON (u.inlog = o.speler AND o.btijd between '$bdatum' AND '$edatum')
WHERE
   code = '$code'
GROUP BY 
   l.inlog
```

If I use this code:

```
SELECT
   l.inlog AS inlog,
   u.naam AS naam,
   SUM(o.status='afgewerkt') AS oefn,
   SUM(b.status='afgewerkt') AS begripn
FROM 
   users AS u
LEFT JOIN     
   llntoets AS l ON (u.inlog = l.inlog)
LEFT JOIN     
   oefeningen AS o ON (u.inlog = o.speler AND o.btijd between '$bdatum' AND '$edatum')
LEFT JOIN     
   begrippen AS b ON (u.inlog = b.speler AND b.btijd between '$bdatum' AND '$edatum')
WHERE
   code = '$code'
GROUP BY 
   l.inlog
```

Even while begrippen and oefeningen the 2 tables have exact the same structure, if I enter the first code, oefn shows the perfect number it should be, if I take the second code it makes numbers that are totally wrong. Can someone help me pls?

Comment: You have to make your questions more understandable if you want people here to help you out with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you join in a table where there are more than one record matching each record that you join against, that will cause records from other joins to be duplicated.

You can use subqueries to count the records from the other tables:

```
select
  l.inlog AS inlog,
  u.naam AS naam,
  (
    select count(*)
    from oefeningen
    where
      speler = u.inlog and
      btijd between '$bdatum' and '$edatum' and
      status = 'afgewerkt'
  ) as oefn,
  (
    select count(*)
    from begrippen
    where
      speler = u.inlog and
      btijd between '$bdatum' and '$edatum' and
      status = 'afgewerkt'
  ) as begripn
from
  users as u
  left join llntoets as l on (u.inlog = l.inlog)
where
  code = '$code'
group by
  l.inlog
```